# Google Sheet App Script - For Specific Sheet Hide Rows that are empty then export to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFgdpoIdUUufvDTmkFvNR1NQ7BBxDiDe1xXf2JSyG0o/edit?usp=sharing/%22Google%20Sheet%20Link%22)

**Updated** with working script

I am having a little bit difficulty figuring how to hide ranges of rows. 
I also notice I am not using the updated api for ui messages.

```
UiApp API is deprecated.Expand
File: PrintOrder Line: 28
Anchor API is deprecated.Expand
File: PrintOrder Line: 31
UiInstance API is deprecated.Expand
File: PrintOrder Line: 28
```

I have a sheet("printOrder" that pulls data from sheet("salesOrder")

My plan is to link a script to button on salesOrder that prints or exports to PDF printOrder.

Now I would like to hide the empty rows that are not filled in between Row 41 to Row 76.  Here is my mangled script so far:

```
function printOrder() {

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("printOrder");
    var gid = sheet.getSheetId();

  //start number Row, start number Column, number of Rows , number of Columns 
    var range = sheet.getRange(41, 1, 36,10); 

  //get the values to those rows
    var values = range.getValues();
    Logger.log(values)

      for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {

         if(values[i][0] === ""){
             sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+41,1));1
         }     
       }

  // Getting 'name' for PDF from Cell G5 
    var name = sheet.getRange("G5").getValue()+".pdf";
  // setting output options  
    var pdfOpts = '&size=letter' +
                  '&fzr=true'+ 
                  '&portrait=true'+
                  '&fitw=true'+
                  '&gridlines=false'+
                  '&printtitle=false'+
                  '&sheetnames=false'+
                  '&pagenum=CENTER'+
                  '&attachment=false'+
                  '&gid=';

  // retrieving url to link for download of pdf
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 
              'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
               pdfOpts + 
               sheet.getSheetId();

  // simple ui popup to allow user to click-download pdf
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(200).setHeight(50);
      app.setTitle('Print this sheet');

    var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_new');
      app.add(link);
      ss.show(app);

 }
```

Thank you for the guidance.

Cheers,

mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate `i` at zero, then when you use the `hideRows()` method, you will need to add 41 to i to hide the correct row:

```
sheet.hideRows(i+41);
```

I think this line has an issue:

```
for (var i=41; i<values.length; i++) {
```

The `values` array has row 41 data in the array index zero.  You can print the contents of the `values` array with a `Logger.log('array: ' + array);` statement.  Add the Logger statement, run the code, and then in the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.

The range that the values are retrieved from starts in row 41, but to loop through the data, `i` needs to start at zero.

```
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
```

You can start the counter number at any number you want, but then you'd need to subtract that number to get to zero for the first loop.

```
var thisLoopValue;

for (var i=41; i<values.length; i++) {
  thisLoopValue = values[i-41]; //On the first iteration, index needs to be zero.  41 - 41 is zero
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it is something very simple, but I am still having some troubles getting the correct range values to hide for export to PDF.  I added a link to a Public Version of the spreadsheet, I am playing with the script: PrintOrder.gs  Thanks!

Comment: Your `for` loop, never even loops once.  `for (var i=41; i<values.length; i++) {`  The length is 33, and `i` is at 41.  The loop will only loop if `i` is less than 33.  The loop never does anything.

Comment: The best thing to do is to initiate `i` at zero.  `i = 0`.  Don't worry about whether the index number is the same as the row number.  That will probably, almost *never* be the case.  When you use the `hideRows()` method, you'll need to adjust by adding 41 to `i`.

Comment: There are two variations of `hideRows()` and then a `hideRow()` method.  So, there are 3 similar possibilities for hiding rows.  It looks like you are trying to use a `range` object for the parameter of `hideRows()`  But `hideRows()` will not accept a range object.  `hideRow()`  (no "s" on the end) will accept a range object, but `hideRows()` just takes a row index as an integer.  [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer))

Comment: Brilliant!  that 's' had me scrambled!